# Add custom button to Pageactions

Tags: magento2, custom-button

I have another problem.

When you edit an order (admin) you will get here:

[image]
The buttons above, marked with the red line, are generated here:

> /module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/pageactions.phtml
>
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if ($block->getChildHtml()):?>
    <div data-mage-init='{"floatingHeader": {}}' class="page-actions" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUiId('content-header') ?>>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to add a custom button "Bestellschein" there.
How can I do that?

Edit: Where can I code the logic of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do that is by adding a plugin to your project. Create:

**\app\code\Custom\Module\registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Custom_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**\app\code\Custom\Module\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**\app\code\Custom\Module\etc\adminhtml\di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="buttons_plugin" type="Custom\Module\Plugin\Buttons" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**\app\code\Custom\Module\Plugin\Buttons.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Plugin;

class Buttons
{
public function beforePushButtons(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
) {

    $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
    if($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){
        $buttonList->add(
            'mybutton',
            ['label' => __('My Button'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation(window.location.href)', 'class' => 'reset'],
            -1
        );
    }

}
}
```

After run:

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: it worked. Where can I code the logic of the button?

Comment: you will need to create a new route and a controller that will handle the request

Comment: I want the button to start a download

Comment: you will need to post another question, because that is another topic